# How do you take every single old ActionListener off of one specific JButton in Java?

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I am working on a BlackJack game and, obviously, I need a hit and stand button.  I have added an `actionListener` to both the hit and stand button in the main method.  But, I cannot figure out how to take off the old `actionListener` for the hit button when the stand button is clicked.  This means that even if you hit "Stand", the hit button still works, and vice versa.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;



public class Jblackjack {
// Creating static variables

    static JButton card1 = new JButton(" ");
    static JButton card2 = new JButton(" ");
    static JButton card3 = new JButton(" ");
    static JButton card4 = new JButton(" ");
    static JButton compcard1 = new JButton(" ");
    static JButton compcard2 =new JButton(" ");
    static JButton compcard3 = new JButton(" ");
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("BlackJack");
    static JButton no = new JButton("Cancel");
    static JButton button = new JButton("Let's go!");
    static JButton hit = new JButton("hit");
    static JButton stand = new JButton("Stand");
    static JLabel comptext = new JLabel("The computer has:");
    static JLabel text = new JLabel("We are going to play Blackjack.");
    static JLabel text2 = new JLabel("This Blackjack does not have any splits, doubles, surrenders, or insurance.  Just hits and stands.");
    static JLabel text3 = new JLabel("This is a WIP");
    static JLabel text4 = new JLabel("11's are Jacks.  12's are Queens.  13's are Kings.  1's are Ones for now.");
    static JLabel text5 = new JLabel("Are you ready?");



    static class Cancel implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    static class Play implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            text.setText("You have:");
            text2.setVisible(false);
            text3.setVisible(false);
            text4.setVisible(false);
            text5.setVisible(false);
            no.setVisible(false);
            button.setVisible(false);
            frame.add(hit);
            frame.add(stand);
            frame.add(card1);
            text.setText("You have:");
            int a = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*4);
            int b = (int)(Math.random()*13);
            if(a==1){
                if((b==11) || (b==12) || (b==13)){
                    b = 10;
                }
                card1.setText(b + "Clubs");
            } else if (a==2){
                if((b==11) || (b==12) || (b==13)){
                    b = 10;
                }
                card1.setText(b + "Spades");
            } else if(a==3){
                if((b==11) || (b==12) || (b==13)){
                    b = 10;
                }
                card1.setText(b + "Hearts");
            } else if(a==4){
                if((b==11) || (b==12) || (b==13)){
                    b = 10;
                }
                card1.setText(b + "Diamonds");
            }
            frame.add(card2);
            int c = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*4);
            int d = (int)(Math.random()*13);
            if(c==1){
                if((d==11) || (d==12) || (d==13)){
                    d = 10;
                }
                card2.setText(d + "Clubs");
            } else if(c==2){
                if((d==11) || (d==12) || (d==13)){
                    d = 10;
                }
                card2.setText(d + "Spades");
            } else if(c==3){
                if((d==11) || (d==12) || (d==13)){
                    d = 10;
                }
                card2.setText(d + "Hearts");
            } else if(c==4){
                if((d==11) || (d==12) || (d==13)){
                    d = 10;
                }
                card2.setText(d + "Diamonds");
            }

            frame.add(comptext);
            comptext.setBounds(10, 350, 200, 50);
            frame.add(compcard1);
            int i = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*4);
            int f = (int)(Math.random()*13);
            if(i==1){
                if((f==11) || (f==12) || (f==13)){
                    f = 10;
                }
                compcard1.setText(f + "Clubs");
            } else if (i==2){
                if((f==11) || (f==12) || (f==13)){
                    f = 10;
                }
                compcard1.setText(f + "Spades");
            } else if(i==3){
                if((f==11) || (f==12) || (f==13)){
                    f = 10;
                }
                compcard1.setText(f + "Hearts");
            } else if(i==4){
                if((f==11) || (f==12) || (f==13)){
                    f = 10;
                }
                compcard1.setText(f + "Diamonds");
            }
            frame.add(compcard2);
            int g = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*4);
            int h = (int)(Math.random()*13);
            if(g==1){
                if((h==11) || (h==12) || (h==13)){
                    h = 10;
                }
                compcard2.setText(h + "Clubs");
            } else if(g==2){
                if((h==11) || (h==12) || (h==13)){
                    h = 10;
                }
                compcard2.setText(h + "Spades");
            } else if(g==3){
                if((h==11) || (h==12) || (h==13)){
                    h = 10;
                }
                compcard2.setText(h + "Hearts");
            } else if(g==4){
                if((h==11) || (h==12) || (h==13)){
                    h = 10;
                }
                compcard2.setText(h + "Diamonds");
            }
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }

    static class Hit implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            hit.removeActionListener(this);
            hit.addActionListener(new Hit2());
            frame.add(card3);
            int a = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*4);
            int b = (int)(Math.random()*13);
            if(a==1){
                if((b==11) || (b==12) || (b==13)){
                    b = 10;
                }
                card3.setText(b + "Clubs");
            } else if (a==2){
                if((b==11) || (b==12) || (b==13)){
                    b = 10;
                }
                card3.setText(b + "Spades");
            } else if(a==3){
                if((b==11) || (b==12) || (b==13)){
                    b = 10;
                }
                card3.setText(b + "Hearts");
            } else if(a==4){
                if((b==11) || (b==12) || (b==13)){
                    b = 10;
                }
                card3.setText(b + "Diamonds");
            }
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }
    static class Hit2 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            hit.removeActionListener(this);
            hit.addActionListener(new Hit3());
            frame.add(card4);
            int c = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*4);
            int d = (int)(Math.random()*13);
            if(c==1){
                if((d==11) || (d==12) || (d==13)){
                    d = 10;
                }
                card4.setText(d + "Clubs");
            } else if(c==2){
                if((d==11) || (d==12) || (d==13)){
                    d = 10;
                }
                card4.setText(d + "Spades");
            } else if(c==3){
                if((d==11) || (d==12) || (d==13)){
                    d = 10;
                }
                card4.setText(d + "Hearts");
            } else if(c==4){
                if((d==11) || (d==12) || (d==13)){
                    d = 10;
                }
                card4.setText(d + "Diamonds");
            }
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }

    static class Hit3 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

        }
    }
    static class Stand implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            frame.add(compcard3);
            int a = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*4);
            int b = (int)(Math.random()*13);
            if(a==1){
                if((b==11) || (b==12) || (b==13)){
                    b = 10;
                }
                compcard3.setText(b + "Clubs");
            } else if (a==2){
                if((b==11) || (b==12) || (b==13)){
                    b = 10;
                }
                compcard3.setText(b + "Spades");
            } else if(a==3){
                if((b==11) || (b==12) || (b==13)){
                    b = 10;
                }
                compcard3.setText(b + "Hearts");
            } else if(a==4){
                if((b==11) || (b==12) || (b==13)){
                    b = 10;
                }
                compcard3.setText(b + "Diamonds");
            }
        }
    }
    static class Stand2 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

        }
    }
    static class Stand3 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //JFrame properties
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Creating "JVariables"
        JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackJackBackGround.png"));

        // Adding JVariables and setting bounds
        card1.setBounds(20, 50, 110, 150);
        card2.setBounds(140, 50, 110, 150);
        card3.setBounds(260, 50, 110, 150);
        card4.setBounds(380, 50, 110, 150);
        hit.setBounds(20, 300, 100, 50);
        hit.addActionListener(new Hit());
        stand.setBounds(130, 300, 100, 50);
        stand.addActionListener(new Stand());
        compcard1.setBounds(20, 400, 110, 150);
        compcard2.setBounds(140, 400, 110, 150);
        compcard3.setBounds(260, 400, 110, 150);
        frame.add(background);
        frame.add(text);
        text.setBounds(5, 0, 250, 50);
        frame.add(text2);
        text2.setBounds(5, 25, 550, 50);
        frame.add(text3);
        text3.setBounds(5, 50, 150, 50);
        frame.add(text4);
        text4.setBounds(5, 75, 550, 50);
        frame.add(text5);
        text5.setBounds(5, 100, 150, 50);
        frame.add(no);
        no.setBounds(10, 150, 150, 50);
        no.addActionListener(new Cancel());
        frame.add(button);
        button.setBounds(170, 150, 150, 50);
        button.addActionListener(new Play());
        frame.setSize(1000, 700);

    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225628/how-to-remove-an-action-listener and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048006/java-swing-how-to-remove-an-anonymous-actionlistener-from-a-component

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Normally, you would have an instance of the `ActionListener` and would simply pass it to `JButton#removeActionListener`, you can, however, remove all the previously registered listeners, but remember, this could have adverse side effects if something else has registered a listener...

Comment: How would I do this?